# How to specify return type as a list of React components with Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I've seen elsewhere people using `React$Element<Type>` so I assumed that to return an array of those would be as simple as adding `[]` to the end. I've tried that here:

```
navbarItems: INavbarItem[];

getNavbarItems(): React$Element<NavbarItem>[] {
  return this.navbarItems.map((navbarItem, index) => {
    return (
      <NavbarItem
        key={index}
        title={navbarItem.title}
        icon={navbarItem.icon}
        listPath={navbarItem.listPath}
        createPath={navbarItem.createPath}
      />
    );
  });
}
```

***NavbarItem***

```
class NavbarItem extends Component<Props, any> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    /* stuff */
  }

  /* Couple of functions */

  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <DropdownTitle/>
        {this.state.open && (
          <ul>
            <MenuItem>List</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Create</MenuItem>
          </ul>
        )}
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I run flow I get the following error:

> Cannot return `this.navbarItems.map(...)` because statics of `NavbarItem` [1] is incompatible with `NavbarItem` [2] in type argument `ElementType` [3] of array element.
>
> [1] class [NavbarItem] extends Component
>
> [2] getNavbarItems(): React$Element<[NavbarItem]>[]
>
> [3] declare type React$Element<+[ElementType]: React$ElementType> (from react.js)

[] above denotes where the ^ are pointing at in the error message. Being new to flow I'm unsure what it means by the statics of my Component here.

Comment: I just tried your code for a same situation and it works ok. Could you add the `NavbarItem` code?

Comment: @KirillGlazunov What specifically do you need to see? Whole class is a bit long is all (reading that back sounds like a candidate for refactoring ha)

Comment: Since the error message contains "statics of `NavbarItem`" I assume it may be caused by some static method or property.

Comment: @KirillGlazunov See edit, I've stripped most of the fluff out.

Comment: It did not help( And what is hidden under error links ([1], [2], [3])?

Comment: @KirillGlazunov I've edited again. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should also probably be using the [`React.Element<typeof Component>`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/website/en/docs/react/types.md#reactelementtypeof-component-) type instead of `React$ElementType<T>`, since the latter is supposed to be internal. The documentation for `React.Element<typeof Component>` also hints that you need to use the [`typeof` operator](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/typeof/) to specify you mean the *type* of the `NavbarItem` class:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA0D09cAyjAK4BGHWAJnBG3gA3LFFTAIAO3QQCcGAAssqLHFwlIkrJJioa66fAAixMDwgB3SQBVgMADaqAvHAAUASjhOAfHADeAL76UqjwALLabACSMFikLh5evoE0MACeYKoACqboLsiSaakZqlEAcshCHMhQMXFe-jRw8naOAFwohQA0TXDABh0FaT3N9sChWciKg929uJRTWJPTnUVB+vZo6BVVNXWkWAAesZI86Nh4MAB0AMIaUtowADw5EGCoXavJcyEwUGz4aCuMC5Dqvd6ePy9ZqoNiZKDA3LuADc0Lg9CQoTYBDkCHovXWzQxcDucMc-DkBDYknwEmkiHxvUop1EiShzWalHYUEkbjRzSeY28-I5TxMb3MVlsDiw9GFHIV-kU4yuoUWVze2jgADJtXzFYqnmx7PKDYaIpJorEQN4ADLjZ70C1WuKms2i537bw3BaxJ5OyJekUK-3Gt2K9xBA3+oVolEEmjrXCbVDoABiEAgjQ5kkq1Vq1tQHXKeb21oA2gBdVG9ADmWBgO3z+1QHg6F3wVwAoo4QI8nulMrI4E2y66q9mOVy2Dz5AoVbndgW4qgriBkGBXK5F83rZ9gCzDp4fJOFdPZ65g3AnqPlyAr80ANZYNJOPwHnhHKPuloyt87scQCuGBWiwb93X6KR-1LO8rkgyRwLNMYJimBRoKXfYrmQmBlgURCDXmHBYlw9DdziK5CMWXD8I5OURXjBUAgYuAggCIA))

```
import * as React from 'react'

// ...

class Foo {
   navbarItems: INavbarItem[];

  getNavbarItems(): React.Element<typeof NavbarItem>[] {
    return this.navbarItems.map((navbarItem, index) => {
      return (
        <NavbarItem
          key={index}
          title={navbarItem.title}
          icon={navbarItem.icon}
          listPath={navbarItem.listPath}
          createPath={navbarItem.createPath}
        />
      );
    });
  }
}
```

This still works if you use `React$ElementType<T>`:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBhCcCAOyWJgF84AzKQuAcilQwYCg2B6TuAZRgCuAIyFIAJnAgD4ANyRQAzsBILJ1ODAAWSBUjhpCkUuQVsDxBfAAidMGIgB3YgBVgMADZ6AvHAAUASjgvAD5cCjMVeABZMgEASRgkECC-QJCwthgATzA9AAVbVR8UYizMnL04gDkUGSEUKASklJw2OA03TwAuOBKszDa4YHMevoH292BLPJQtUdLx-WZZpBm53tK2cLN3FAVVGrqGpuSkAA9E4jFVAiJjGAAeAogwBWw+0Nb280soAQxoL4wIUes9XoEvu04AoBLkoEDCv4ANyDdqcABU0ME1HU6M4g22aMxBFhnjUNAExAwygscDxHHazCu8gCuFRcGYgigxD87PaD0mwT5UIeNhe9icrg8SE4Qqh8twWimADpLCtlS8yHAAGTa3kKhUPATuOUGw0xYjxRIgYIAGSmj04FqtSVNZpFzpOwTwy0SDydsS9wvl-uNboV-nCBv9gvZyIJWw4aF2+zgADEIBA2VDiLV6o1rQoetU88drQBtAC6KMGAHMkDBDvmTgoAj1kOgYAASACinhAZEe2VyEHUTbLrqr2ahnIE3I0mhVuaOBaSCmVIBQYF8vmXzet2GAzLOaU+wtn898wbgD3Hq5A1-aAGskFkvDgj2JzlH3R1pe+9wnEBlRgTokB-d1hhIADS3vZUoOICCzUmaZZk0GCVxOZUUJgNZNCQg00F9VY0Iw-ckmVIjUESPCCKhWVhXjeUKCYuBwgoIA))

```
class Foo {
   navbarItems: INavbarItem[];

  getNavbarItems(): React$Element<typeof NavbarItem>[] {
    return this.navbarItems.map((navbarItem, index) => {
      return (
        <NavbarItem
          key={index}
          title={navbarItem.title}
          icon={navbarItem.icon}
          listPath={navbarItem.listPath}
          createPath={navbarItem.createPath}
        />
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, apologies in the delay to accept. Only back in the office today to check it out